# Setter for dictionary property - OR: get last added item from dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a custom class with different computed properties. One of them is a `Dictionary` of `[String: String]`. The getter is no problem, but I don't know how to use the setter: How can I figure out, what was the last value added to the dictionary? Obviously `newValue.last` doesn't exists (.first does!).

**EDIT:**

This seems to work:

```
var myProp: [String: String] {
    get { ... }
    set {
        let lastVal = newValue[newValue.startIndex.advancedBy(newValue.count-1)]
        ...
    }
```

BUT: will this always return the last added value?

**EDIT 2**

The first edit is *wrong*. A dictionary is unordered and with this way it's not sure, if it really returns the last added key and value. See my answer below.

Comment: A dictionary is an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs. The pair returned by `first` need not be the one that was added first to the dictionary.

Comment: Ahhhh, you was faster than my edit ;) Thanks. This means my assumption is right, that the order can be different as the order of addition?

Comment: Yes, you should not make any assumptions on the order of key/value pairs in a dictionary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand now... the dictionary is unordered. To really get the last added value, I have to compare the value itself with the newValue. The working code:

```
var myProp: [String: String] {
    get { // doing things to read the things and add them to a dictionary }
    set {
        var new = newValue
        for (key, value) in myProp {
            if new[key] == value {
                new.removeValueForKey(key)
            }
        }
        // now 'new' should only have one key and one value, that one, that just was added
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you point out, a Dictionary is an *unorderd* collection of key-value pairs, so there is no `last` getter (`first` is just a convenience for what in Objective-C was more appropriately called `anyObject`) . The Dictionary also does not keep track of the order items were added.

To get the last item, there are two possibilities. You could refactor to use an array, e.g. of tuples `(key, value)`; or you could keep track of the last item added in a separate variable.

But maybe there is a misunderstanding about the "setter". A setter *sets* the entire object.

```
set { myProp = newValue }
```

So if you have a `myProp = ["foo": "bar"]`, the entire dictionary in myProp is overwritten with this data.

What you want is to **add** a key to the property. In Swift, this is done by subscripting.

```
myProp["foo"] = "bar"
```

You do not have to implement anything special in the `get` closure.

Note that you have to remember two things, though: first, the dictionary has to be properly initialized; second, any *existing* item will be overwritten if the new value uses the identical `key`.

Comment: There is a reason, why I'm using a getter and a setter and thanks, but there is no misunderstanding. I'm using libxml and in the getter part I'm reading the attributes of a node, in the setter part I want to set them... but only the one what was changed. I have the solution, the answer follows ...

Comment: That was not clear in your question. You can iterate through the items and check which one is new.

Comment: Yes, maybe it was not totally clear, but as you said: Otherwise my question wouldn't make any sense ;) My solution does know do an iteration.